# Why is are button onclick event not working?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html page with two buttons. In my script I have functions for those button's onclick event, but when I click on those buttons, nothing happens. In the console I see the following error:

### TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

on the line of my button function.

**My Script:**

```
var page = 0;
var panel = 0;
var panelNumber = [2,6,6,5];

window.addEventListener('load', findPage);

function findPage() {
    for (panel = 0; panel < panelNumber[page]; panel++) {
        var elem = document.createElement("img");
        elem.setAttribute("src", "../Images/" + page + "." + panel + ".jpg");
        elem.setAttribute("width", "100%");
        document.getElementById("chapter").appendChild(elem);
    }
};    

document.getElementById("next").onclick = function () {
    if (page < panelNumber.length) {
        page++;
        findPage();
    }    
};

document.getElementById("first").onclick = function () {
    if (page != 0) {
        page = 0;
        findPage();
    }    
};

document.getElementById("previous").onclick = function () {
    if (page > 0) {
        page--;
        findPage();
    }    
};
```

**My HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="../css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../css/MyStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/MyScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="container-fluid"> 
    <ul class="nav nav-pills navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
        <li><button id="previous" class="btn btn-default">previous</button></li>
        <li><button id="first" class="btn btn-default" >first</button></li>
        <li><button id="next" class="btn btn-default">next</button></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-lg-2" id="left"></div>    
        <div class="col-lg-8" id="page">
            <div id="chapter"></div>
            <div id="comments"></div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've already scrolled through a lot of the same question here, but the answer was `window.addEventListener('load')`, and I already did that.

Comment: You will need to include all the `document.getElementById("...").onclick` calls in your `findPage()` function.

Comment: Is this flagged as jQuery because if you actually used jQuery then you wouldn't have these problems?

Comment: @RichLinnell, No. It's flagged as jquery because I didn't know what jquery is, and that tag was suggested. i guess I'll take that tag off...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of now the code is executed without page content be loaded in DOM. When you are adding event handler in statement

```
document.getElementById("next").onclick = function () {
```

You need to wait for DOM to build. You should use [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event

> The `DOMContentLoaded` event is fired when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
    //Your code to bind event handler

    document.getElementById("next").onclick = function () {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code fails at this line

```
document.getElementById("next").onclick = function () {
```

Because the element can't be found at the time your script runs. Place your scripts at the end of your `<body>`:

```
    </div>

    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/MyScript.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Great addition, haven't thought about that potential issue!